# What does Derpy's cutie mark mean?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

This is Derpy:

[image: Derpy]

As we know, in the MLP:FiM universe, cutie marks indicate a pony's special talent or individualizing feature.

Derpy's is a bunch of bubbles.

[image: bubblesmark]

What does this cutie mark mean? Or, more fully, what is Derpy's special talent?

Comment: Would it be immature to say "farts"? I think it would. I won't say that.

Answer (score 12):

This may be too much of a [general-reference sort of question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derpy_Hooves#Derpy_Hooves), but still.

Out-of-universe, she was originally just a background pony/pegasus and the bubbles mean nothing.

In-universe, Derpy is cheerful yet clumsy, so the bubbles are a reference to being a bit of a bubblehead.

(Note: Despite the gravatar I've used since Christmas 2011, I am not a "brony," but I've watched all of S1 of MLP and most of the MLP movies from the generation just before FIM with my daughter.)

Comment: You should definitely watch season 2, it really picks up shortly into that.

Answer (score 7):

Her "Bubbles" cutie mark is because of Faust's liking of The Powerpuff girls, and one of the Powerpuff girls, called "Bubbles" often acts silly (or Derpy) at times.

Comment: Did Faust confirm this in an interview somewhere?

Comment: Faust didn't just like Powerpuff Girls, she [worked on that show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauren_Faust#Television).  A lot of the style (action, characterisation) of MLP was influenced by her time there.  That said, your answer needs a reference, quote, or something to prove your statement.

Answer (score 5):

In a twit, Lauren Faust confirmed that Derpy's cutie mark was in fact **helium bubbles**.

> *Regarding pegasus helium farts: I think we finally know what Derpy's
> cutie mark is.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/fyre_flye/status/291359884727951360)</sup></sub>

That being said, I suspect she might have been joking.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard about derpys cutie mark having to do with bubble wrap because she supposedly deliveres mail. So i guess she wraps it in bubble wrap. The power puff girl thing is most likely though

Comment: Ah! I never thought of that! I'd personally accept the bubble wrap theory as most canon.

Answer (score 1):

Someone once said that it may have something to do with diving/swimming, due to some evidence related to a book in the show (I don't remember the details)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Scifi.SE. Can you add a source for those details ? That would be great

Answer (score -1):

Derpy is bright, cheerful, and bubbly, so I think it would be appropriate to say it *is* a bunch of bubbles, because derpy is so full of life and never looks at the bad side of things!

Answer (score -2):

This answer is tricky, but I think the bubbles refer to the girl Bubbles from the PowerPuff Girls because Bubbles looks like her sisters but is completely clueless, just like derpy.